# In Harry Potter, can a memory be implanted into someone else using the Memory Extraction Spell?

Tags: harry-potter

[image]

Can a memory be implanted from one person to another by placing the memories into someone's head after extracting it?

Comment: It's shown that it can be added, but I'm not sure whether you'd use this technique to do so.

Comment: What is a "Memory Extraction Spell"? Is that a wiki term?

Answer (score 3):

### There is a way to implant memories, though it's unclear if it's related to extracting them

> “So Voldemort stole Morfin’s wand and used it?” said Harry, sitting up straight.
>   “That’s right,” said Dumbledore. “We have no memories to 
>   show us this, but I think we can be fairly sure what happened. Voldemort Stupefied his uncle, took his wand, and proceeded across the valley to ‘the big house over the way’ There he murdered the Muggle man who had abandoned his witch mother, and, for good measure, his Muggle grandparents, thus obliterating the last of the unworthy Riddle line and revenging himself upon the father 
>   who never wanted him. Then he returned to the Gaunt hovel, performed **the complex bit of magic that would implant a false memory** in his uncle’s mind, laid Morfin’s wand beside its unconscious owner, pocketed the ancient ring he wore, and departed.”
>   “And Morfin never realized he hadn’t done it?”
>   “Never,” said Dumbledore. “He gave, as I say, a full and boastful confession.”
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - Chapter 17</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The [False Memory Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/False_Memory_Charm) is a spell which can be used by a witch or wizard in order to add a memory to their victim's mind without the victim realising it was not originally theirs.

This is generally used to implant a fictitious memory, but there's no reason the memory implanted can't simply be a real one from another person. However, when using this method, the person you put the memory into will believe its theirs.

It is possible to modify a memory and still retain knowledge of the true one, as this is exactly what Horace Slughorn did in order to hide his association with Tom Riddle on the subject of Horcruxes.

However, to answer the main question, no, it isn't possible to implant a memory specifically by using the **Memory Extraction Spell**. The clue is in the name, it's used to *extract* memories, nothing else. If you want to implant a memory into somebody else, you'll have to use another method, probably a **False Memory Charm** or some variant of it.