# In Order of the Phoenix, why doesn't Harry just use a pensieve to prove Voldemort had returned?

Tags: harry-potter, pensieve

At the beginning of Order of the Phoenix, when nobody believes Harry that Voldemort had returned, why didn't he just show everyone what happened via a pensieve. Surely there is no way to dispute the hard evidence in Harrys memories of his encounter with Voldemort at the end of Goblet of Fire

Comment: Semi-dupe of [Why didn't Harry, Ron, Hermione, and Lupin collectively put their memories of the unveiling of Wormtail into a pensieve?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132723/why-didnt-harry-ron-hermione-and-lupin-collectively-put-their-memories-of-th/132729#132729) and [In Harry Potter, can a memory be implanted into someone else using the Memory Extraction Spell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/in-harry-potter-can-a-memory-be-implanted-into-someone-else-using-the-memory-ex/155948#155948) - Memory in the HP universe can be self-edited or implanted by another.

Comment: I [closed your question as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of the linked question. If you think it's not a duplicate feel free to [edit] your question to explain why.

Comment: Because memories can be faked and fudge would have called him a bloody idiot for trying to fool the ministry!